# StructureMap register single component type to satisfy more than one service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

In the old version (2.5) of Structure Map it was possible to:

```
ForRequestedType<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>()
                .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid)
                .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<EventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>();

ForRequestedType<IUnitOfWork>()
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(x => x.GetInstance<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>());
```

How do I do it in StructureMap v4.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jeremy Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3569026/jeremy-d-miller) from StructureMap itsef came to help and it is:

```
For<IUnitOfWork>().Use(x => x.GetInstance<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>());
```

for the questioned:

```
ForRequestedType<IUnitOfWork>()
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(x => x.GetInstance<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>());
```

Thanks Jeremy!